# Why isnt my for loop continuing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to get the title and view count from YouTube videos based on their id. I have that part working, but for some reason my for loop isnt continuing past the first iteration. I am very, VERY new to JavaScript, and was wondering if anyone could help me. Thank you. Code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEDxBeaconStreetViewCount</title>

<script type="text/javascript">



var de;
var numVids = 2;

var videos = new Array("Evi357e1spA", "le2dkeYnEzA");

    function start(){

    for(var i = 0; i < numVids+1; i++){

    de = 'demo_' + i.toString();
        //          alert(de);
    getVideoInformation(videos[i], de); return(false);

                              //console.log (de);
    }


    }
    function registerScript(url) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    }

    function videoInfoCallback(info) {
        if (info.error) {
            alert('Error\n\n' + info.error.message);
        } else {
            var title = info.data.title;
            var viewCount = info.data.viewCount;
            try {
                if (JSON && JSON.stringify) {
                    message += "\n\n" + JSON.stringify(info);
                }
            } catch (e) {
            }
            document.getElementById(de).innerHTML = "Title: " + title + "<br>"     + "Views: " + viewCount;
        }
    }

    function getVideoInformation(vID) {
        var id = vID;
            registerScript('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + id + '?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=videoInfoCallback');

    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="start()" value="Get Video information" />

<p id="demo_0">_</p>

<p id="demo_1">_</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It only runs once because you have a return statement in your loop, which will make it exit the start function altogether.

```
 function start(){   
    for(var i = 0; i < numVids+1; i++){   
        de = 'demo_' + i.toString();       
        getVideoInformation(videos[i], de); 

        //the statement below makes it exit the function
        return(false);

    }
}
```

You can get rid of the numVids variable altogether also.  Maybe you want to try to change it to something like:

```
function start(){

    for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++){
         de = 'demo_' + i.toString();
         getVideoInformation(videos[i], de); 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That solves one of the problems! Thanks, but now I'm presented with another. Without the return statement for the getVideoInformation, it doesn't work. Any idea why it needs it, and how I can use it but still have the for loop work?

Comment: I think you are running your for loop one too many times.  Try making the for loop 'for(var i = 0; i < numVids; i++){' (without the single quotes, instead of 'for(var i = 0; i < numVids+1; i++){'

Comment: I think the < numVids + 1 is the problem

Comment: When I try the second piece of code that you provied, only the second video appears, leading me to believe that it needs to return false for every iteration of the loop, not just after the loop has finished.

Comment: @user2884427 I think you need to change `document.getElementById(de).innerHTML = "Title: " + title + "<br>"` to `document.getElementById(de).innerHTML += "Title: " + title + "<br>"` (changed the `=` to `+=`)...otherwise the `innerHTML` is being overwritten each time, and you'll only see the last iteration's results

Comment: I modified my second function to reflect the updated for loop code as well